# Simple import is throwing an error; any ideas on why I'm not able to import whisper using python?

Tags: python-3.x, openai-whisper

I was able to successfully run my code earlier today, but as of this evening I am getting a syntax error when trying to import Whisper. Any ideas?

```
line 9, in <module>
    import whisper
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whisper/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .audio import load_audio, log_mel_spectrogram, pad_or_trim
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whisper/audio.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .utils import exact_div
  File "/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whisper/utils.py", line 108
    if word_timings := segment.get("words", None):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) raising the error is only available since Python 3.8. It seems you are working with Python 3.7.